# Error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ABC' to data type int."

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need some help with an error I am getting in SQL Server. I have the following lines in my query that is searching in column 'UserCode', and then sums column 'Amount' based on those codes. However, in the usercode column, there are some variables such as "ABC" instead of all integers. This causes an error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ABC' to data type int. I've tried searching but could not find a way around it. Could anyone please advise what would be the best way to overcome this error?

```
SUM((CASE WHEN (ec.UserCode >= 100 AND ec.UserCode <= 200) 
          THEN e.Amount 
          ELSE '0' 
     END)
   ) AS 'ColumnName'
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the schema and sample data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `else` is returning a string, so that is one problem.  Another would be caused only if `e.Amount` were stored as a string -- horror of horrors, not storing a value with the correct type.

So, if that is the code that causing the problems, I would recommend:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ec.UserCode >= 100 AND ec.UserCode <= 200
         THEN TRY_CONVERT(?, e.Amount)
         ELSE 0
    END) AS ColumnName
```

`?` is a place holder for the appropriate type, which might be `int`, `bigint`, `decimal(20, 4)` or something similar.

I should note:  The error could also be caused if `UserCode` is a string.  For that, use string comparisons:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ec.UserCode >= '100' AND ec.UserCode <= '200'
         THEN TRY_CONVERT(?, e.Amount)
         ELSE 0
    END) AS ColumnName
```

Or, if you prefer, `try_convert()` there:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int, ec.UserCode) >= 100 AND
              TRY_CONVERT(int, ec.UserCode <= 200
         THEN TRY_CONVERT(?, e.Amount)
         ELSE 0
    END) AS ColumnName
```

Comment: Gordon, this helped a LOT! The "Try_Convert"() statement worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `TRY_CONVERT` which will return `null` if the conversion fails
Then you can test for `null` or replace those with a 0

```
CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(float, ec.UserCode) IS NULL   
    THEN 0  
    ELSE CONVERT(float, ec.UserCode)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using ISNUMERIC function:

```
select SUM((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC (UserCode) = 0 then 0  
                 when (ec.UserCode >= 100 AND ec.UserCode <= 200) THEN ec.Amount 
            ELSE '0' END)) AS 'ColumnName'
from test ec;
```

Check if it is non numeric, if it is not then you can put 0 because it is not between 100 bad 200.

You can also replace >= <= with between:

```
select SUM((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC (UserCode) = 0 then 0  
                 when (ec.UserCode between 100 and 200) THEN ec.Amount 
            ELSE '0' END)) AS 'ColumnName'
from test ec;
```

[Here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fe98da93d55ea6d14330fcac04dc2c53)

In case the column amount is also varchar you can apply the same on it:

```
select SUM((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC (UserCode) = 0 then 0  
                 when (ec.UserCode between 100 and 200) 
                       and ISNUMERIC(ec.Amount) > 0 THEN ec.Amount 
            ELSE '0' END)) AS 'ColumnName'
from test ec;
```

Comment: TRY_CONVERT is a much better approach than ISNUMERIC. That function is really pretty horrible. It returns way too many false positives. Values like $, ¢ and 1e4 all return true. Even some fun things like char(10) and some other system characters return true. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/why-doesn%e2%80%99t-isnumeric-work-correctly-sql-spackle